# Access public method of same level class in Java using Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

```
public class A{

}

//this class is in the same file as A class i.e. A.java
class B{

   //has a public method
}
```

**THESE BOTH CLASSES ARE IN SAME FILE.**
So cannot make class `B` as `public`.

On trying to access the public method of class `B` which is defined at same level as class `A` using Reflection, it gives me `IllegalAccessException` that cannot access member of class `B` with modifiers `public`.

Is there any way I can achieve it using reflection?

Comment: Can you show how you call it?

Answer (score 1):

Made your class **B** as public and then try. It should work.

Quoting java docs

> A member (class, interface, field, or method) of a reference (class, interface, or array) type or a constructor of a class type is accessible only if the type is accessible and the member or constructor is declared to permit access

Answer (score 0):

You need to [`setAccesible(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible%28boolean%29) on that method.

Comment: You cannot do setAccessible on class